# C# How to convert text formatted number with exclamation mark icon note to number formatted number?

Tags: c#, excel, number-formatting

[image]

I tried to convert them to number format in C#
I have tried as the below but it does not convert.
Does anybody have an idea how to convert these type data to number format?

```
range.NumberFormat = "0";
```

Comment: from your image I see `68085` are you staying that you want to convert `!68085` to a number removing the `!` if so then why not use the `.Contains` method or the `string.Replace` to remove the `!` for example 
`var someblaNum = Convert.ToInt32(YourTextValue.Replace("!", ""));`

Comment: Can you explain what the initial format is and what you desire? @MethodMan is exactly right if he has your scenario down right

Comment: @MethodMan I think OP is referring to the cell marked with yellow exclamation mark and not `!68085`.

Comment: I did not know the value actually has "!" at the beginning because it does not show. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Changing the number format of the cells won't do anything, since it only affects the visual presentation of a numeric value and the values are strings, not numbers.

You will need to convert the numbers from strings to a compatible numeric type - `double`, or `int` depending on the content, maybe even `Decimal` - and replace the string values with the converted numeric.

Something like this (untested) might do it:

```
foreach (var cell in range.Cells)
{
    double value;
    if (double.TryParse(cell.Value.ToString(), out value))
        cell.Value = value;
}
```

Comment: This is the correct answer for this question. Because the value you are using string that's why in excel will ask you to convert it to number.

Comment: @pnuts Was that directed to me?  If so... the text of the question shows that the OP was trying to solve the problem by setting `range.NumberFormat` which wasn't going to work.  That's what I was referring to.

Comment: @pnuts That's OK, I assumed there was a misunderstanding there somewhere... just wasn't sure if it was yours or mine :)